# What's wrong with my structs?

Tags: c, vector, struct

Ok, i'm writing in c here. Compiling in mingw gcc.

I'm trying to do something really simple. create a vector struct containing 3 floats x,y,z.

then I want to be able to do some math with them.

This is my short test program:

```
#ifndef _PHYSICS_C_
#define _PHYSICS_C_


    #define SUCCESS  0
    #define FAILURE  1


    typedef struct {
        float x;
        float y;
        float z;
    }vector;

    int add ( vector* a, vector* b, vector* destination ){
        (*destination).x = (float)( ((*a).x) + ((*b).x) );
        (*destination).y = (float)( ((*a).y) + ((*b).y) );
        (*destination).z = (float)( ((*a).z) + ((*b).z) );      
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    int main(int argc, char** argv){

        printf("creating vectors\n\n");
        vector a = {1.0f,5.0f,3.0f};
        vector b = {2.0f,3.0f,6.0f};
        vector destination;

        printf("adding vectors\n\n");
        if(add(&a, &b, &destination) == SUCCESS){       
            printf("result: (%d, %d, %d)\n\n",destination.x,destination.y,destination.z);
        } else {
            printf("the program failed somehow...\n\n");
        }

        printf("Press any key to continue...\n");
        getchar();

        return SUCCESS;
    }

#endif
```

When I compile and run it, it should return (3, 8, 9) the sum of vectors a and b.

instead it returns (0, 1074266112, 0)...

I can't figure out what is wrong.

for some reason I think that I must somehow be writing over memory I'm not supposed to.

Comment: You can use the `->` operator instead of `*(x).y`, along with dropping the superflous parenthesis, this will make your code more readable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

x,y,z are floats but you are trying to print them as integers.

try:

```
        printf("result: (%f, %f, %f)\n\n",destination.x,destination.y,destination.z);
```

check `man printf` or your documentation to see all of the specifiers for printf.

Answer (score 0):

`%d` expects `int`. Use `%f` or `%g` for floats/doubles.

Answer (score 0):

You are printing `float` with format specifier `%d` which is intended for `signed int`. Use `%f` or `%g` or `%e` instead .

Also, why don't you do:

```
    destination->x = a->x + b->x;
```

Its much easier on the eyes. (although not a problem).

Comment: `%d` is intended for signed `int`, not for signed integers in general (`long` is a signed integer type, but it's not `int`).  `%f`, `%g`, and `%e` are correct formats for either float or double arguments; float arguments are promoted to double in this context.

Answer (score 0):

Identifiers starting with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter are reserved; don't use them in your own code.

Include guards (`#ifndef _PHYSICS_C_ ...`) are for header files, not for `.c` files.

`printf` requires `#include <stdio.h>`.

You're returning the value `SUCCESS` from `main()`.  That's ok, since `SUCCESS` happens to be 0, but it would be clearer to use either `EXIT_SUCCESS` (declared in `<stdlib.h>` or just `return 0;`.

You `add` function always returns `SUCCESS`.  It might as well be a void function (and the test for its value in `main` is not useful).  Unless you anticipate adding error checking later on.

The casts in your `add` function are unnecessary; the expression is already of type `float`.  And `(*foo).bar` is better written as `foo->bar`.  For example, the first assignment can be simplified to `destination->x = a->x + y->x;`.

The real problem (which has already been pointed out) is that you're using a `"%d"` format for values of type `float`.

It's usual to use `double` rather than `float`. It has more precision, and modern hardware is often optimized for double-precision operations.

If you enable warnings in your compiler, it will probably tell you about some of these problems.